# increase player speed based on score (endless skiing game)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am am making an endless skiing game, similar to alto and ski safari, and need help in increasing the speed of my player based on the score of the tricks (backflips, etc) he has performed. Here's the code I've written so far:
(this script calculates the score of the player based on backflip)

```cs
public class tricksScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float flips = 0;
    private float deltaRotation = 0;
    private float currentRotation = 0;
    private float WindupRotation = 0;
    public static Rigidbody2D rigbod;
    float divideByNum = 0.25f;
    public Text scores;
    public int trickscore;
    private int iflip;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        scores = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        deltaRotation = (currentRotation - rigbod.transform.eulerAngles.z);
        currentRotation = rigbod.transform.eulerAngles.z;
        if (deltaRotation >= 300)
            deltaRotation -= 360;
        if (deltaRotation <= -300)
            deltaRotation += 360;
        WindupRotation += (deltaRotation);
        flips = WindupRotation / 340;
        iflip = (int)flips;
        iflip = iflip * -1;
        trickscore = iflip * 10;
        Debug.Log(trickscore);
        scores.text = "score " + trickscore;
    }
}
```

i import the variable trickscore to the script responsible for character movement:

```cs
[SerializeField] private tricksScore trickscript;
public int trickscore;
public int oldScore = 0;
public int incInScore;
trickscore = trickscript.trickscore;

incInScore = trickscript.trickscore - oldScore;
if (incInScore >= 10)
{
    oldScore = trickscript.trickscore;
}
if (incInScore > 1 && incInScore <= 10)
{
    speed = speed + 10.15f;
}
else if (incInScore > 10 && incInScore <= 20)
{
    speed = speed + 0.25f;
}
else if (incInScore > 20 && incInScore <= 50)
{
    speed = speed + 0.50f;
}
else if (incInScore > 50 && incInScore <= 100)
{
    speed = speed + 0.75f;
}
else if (incInScore > 100 && incInScore <= 200)
{
    speed = speed + 1f;
}
else if (incInScore > 200)
{
    speed = speed + 2f;
}
```

the problem is that the speed of the player doesnt increase when i perform a backflip, also i think the variable that stores the score of the player (trickscore) also has broken because prior to writing the script, it used to display the players score in the console (debug.log) and in the text object ("scores") but neither happens anymore. i am a complete code noobie and this is the first game i am making , and this porblem has had the entire development stuck for a many days, so i will greatly appreciate any and all help. Thank you

Comment: Why do you increase the speed with 10.15 when you are lower than 10 but with 0.25 if you are higher than then? Was it a typo, if yes I wouldn't use 7 if elses but just caluculate speed increase with the incInScore. For example: `speed += (Mathf.Round(incInScore)) / 100.0;`

Comment: Also make sure that trickscript is set in the inspector.

Comment: i increase it by 10 cuz rn the most score u can make is 10 and if i gav it a small value it would be hard to see if the code has started working. also yes the trickscript does appear in the inspector. do u have any fixes for my code?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you have both scripts attached to your gameobject, the ideal would be separate the calculations and have 1 script handling it, get used to that and you will save yourself a lot of bugs (way better than pass scripts around and have a lot of confusion), an example in one file (that also should work if your player "currentSpeed" is used):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class tricksScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float flips = 0;
    private float deltaRotation = 0;
    private float currentRotation = 0;
    private float WindupRotation = 0;
    public static Rigidbody2D rigbod;
    float divideByNum = 0.25f;
    public Text scores;
    public int trickscore;
    private int iflip;
    public int oldScore = 0;
    public int incInScore;
    public float currentSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        scores = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        deltaRotation = (currentRotation - rigbod.transform.eulerAngles.z);
        currentRotation = rigbod.transform.eulerAngles.z;
        if (deltaRotation >= 300)
            deltaRotation -= 360;
        if (deltaRotation <= -300)
            deltaRotation += 360;
        WindupRotation += (deltaRotation);
        flips = WindupRotation / 340;
        iflip = (int)flips;
        iflip = iflip * -1;
        trickscore = iflip * 10;

        currentSpeed += Calculations.CalculateSpeed(trickscore,oldScore);
    }


}
//this should be in a separate file
public class Calculations
{
    public static float CalculateSpeed(float currentScore, float oldScore)
    {
        var incInScore = currentScore - oldScore;

        if (incInScore > 1 && incInScore <= 10)
        {
            return 10.15f;
        }
        else if (incInScore > 10 && incInScore <= 20)
        {
            return 0.25f;
        }
        else if (incInScore > 20 && incInScore <= 50)
        {
            return 0.50f;
        }
        else if (incInScore > 50 && incInScore <= 100)
        {
            return 0.75f;
        }
        else if (incInScore > 100 && incInScore <= 200)
        {
            return 1f;
        }
        else
        {
            return 2f;
        }
    }
}
```